# show taxonomy meta field in template

Tags: taxonomy-meta

i add some custom meta field to product taxonomy "artist"
they work well and save to taxonomy

```
    /**
add meta data to artist taxonomy */

function artist_add_meta_fields( $taxonomy ) {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="artist_nickname"><?php _e( 'Nickname', 'my-plugin' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="artist_nickname" name="artist_nickname" />
    </div>

    <?php
}
add_action( 'artist_add_form_fields', 'artist_add_meta_fields', 10, 2 );


function artist_edit_meta_fields( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $artist_nickname = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'artist_nickname', true );
     ?>

    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="artist_nickname"><?php _e( 'Nickname', 'my-plugin' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="artist_nickname" name="artist_nickname" value="<?php echo $artist_nickname; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
add_action( 'artist_edit_form_fields', 'artist_edit_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

function artist_save_taxonomy_meta( $term_id, $tag_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['artist_nickname'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'artist_nickname', esc_attr( $_POST['artist_nickname'] ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'created_artist', 'artist_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_artist', 'artist_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
```

but i cant get them in taxonomy-artist.php in frontend

```
//Get Taxonomy Meta
$artist_nickname = get_term_meta($term->term_id,'artist_nickname');
echo $artist_nickname;
```

but nothing displayed.
where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display in archive or category (taxonomy) template, try this:

```
$artist_nickname = get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'artist_nickname', true);
echo $artist_nickname;
```

Comment: thanks its working . can i insert a conditional show item? if the term exist show the term

Comment: how i can image taxonomy in archive template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$youvaribale = get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'fieldname', true);
```

OR

```
$youvaribale = get_term_meta( catid, 'fieldname', true);

echo $youvaribale;
```

Comment: how i can get image taxonomy?